# Dice experiment, increasing maximum amount of throws

Tags: c, arrays

I was building a simple program to count the frequencies of the numbers in a dice experiment, but I tried to expand it and increase the maximum amount of throws to huge numbers, and by trial and error I found the max limit to be 519253.

With this maximum value I can’t create any new arrays either, it crashes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#define MX 519253
#define DICE 6
void throwdice(int n[], int size);
int genNum();
void printv(int n[], int size);
void countd(int n[], int size, int count[DICE]);
int main ()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int throws[MX];
    int count[DICE]={0};
    int n;
    //printf("Number of dice to throw: ");
    //scanf("%d",&n);
    n=MX;
    throwdice(throws,n);
    //printf("Throw\tNumber");
    //printv(throws,n);
    countd(throws,n,count);
    printf("\n\nNumber\tFrequency");
    printv(count,DICE);
}
int genNum()
{
    int n;
    n=rand()%DICE+1;
    return n;
}

void printv(int n[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("\n%d  \t%d",i+1,n[i]);
}

void throwdice(int n[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        n[i]=genNum();
}

void countd(int n[], int size, int count[DICE])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        count[n[i]-1]++;
}
```

Is there a way to expand this program to account for, say a million throws?

Comment: Yes it does, in a lot of ways actually!

Comment: You may want to create a structure and pass that around than some arbitrary `int*/size_t` pair.

Comment: Try a new approach.  If you allocate space, the MX number will be larger, your are still limited to the memory resources of the machine.  Instead, perform the `countd()` as code generates on each 1 dice roll, then you can go on and on, only limited by the time you want to take.

Comment: Sidenote: `int genNum();` is not a valid prototype, your compiler should complain. If you don't have parameters, use `void`: `int genNum(void)`. Similar for the definitions. This allies to **all** functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this;

```
int throws[MX];
```

to either this, or move it to a global scope;

```
static int throws[MX];
```

I think you're probably overflowing the stack.

You can try to put the array on the heap like this;

```
int *throws = malloc(sizeof(int)*MX);
```

Comment: I tried both methods and both work perfectly, is there any difference between using static and malloc?

Comment: @RagdeNutzer `malloc` : dynamic memory allocation, size is determined at runtime. `static` : size is determined at compile time. Your C text book contains this information.

Comment: @RagdeNutzer: `static` objects are initialized to zero (or pointers to null pointers), which is a waste in your case since you assign other values to the elements of `throw` without using any initial value first. So using `malloc` would avoid this needless initialization (although a good compiler might recognize that your code does not benefit from the initialization and could optimize it away). (Except the operating system has to zero/randomize memory before it gives it to your process anyway, to avoid disclose other processes’ data. Computing is complicated.)